# How to get API Gateway ID as output section from the serverless when lambda functions are deployed

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, serverless

I want to get the ID of the API Gateway in the output section of the serverless and then convert it into API URL "https://fgh5t4tjm2.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev" which I am using in another serverless.

Below is my api gateway setup by the lambda creation in the serverless script. I think It’s one of the more hidden creations that serverless does where just by setting up an event on the lambda it creates an api gateway for you. I’m not sure if it outputs the API gateway ID at the output section of the serverless.yml.

This is how my serverless looks like.

```
service: my-service

provider:
  name: aws
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  region: ${env:AWS_REGION}
  stackName: my-stack-name

plugins:
  - serverless-dotenv-plugin

functions:
  GetCallHistory:
    handler: lambdas/getCallHistory.GetCallHistory
    environment:
      CH_CW_LOG_GROUP_NAME: ${env:CH_CW_LOG_GROUP_NAME}
    description: This lambda queries cloudwatch logs and retrieves the call history using a contactId.
    role: GetCallHistoryRole
    events:
      - http:
          path: callhistory/{contactId}
          method: get
          cors: true
          authorizer:
            name: CognitoPoolAuthorizer
            type: COGNITO_USER_POOLS
            arn: ${env:COGNITO_USER_POOL_ARN}
resources:
  #Lambda Roles
  - ${file(resources/lambdaRoles.yml)}
```

I am not sure where the **outputs section would go in my serverless** and what to write in order to get the API ID or URL.

Answer (score 0):

Great question: I still have a working template.yml around (though it's in JSON but just pretend it's yml)!

Just reference to the "ApiGateWay" that's within your resources

```
"ApiGatewayApi": {
  "Type": "AWS::Serverless::Api",
  "Properties": {
    "StageName": { "Ref": "environment" },
    "DefinitionBody": "",
    "EndpointConfiguration": "REGIONAL"
  }
},
```

Below an example on how I reference within a url and output the resources:

```
"Outputs" : {
    "ApiURL" : {
        "Description" : "API endpoint URL for ${environment} environment",
        "Value" : { "Fn::Sub" : "https://${ApiGatewayApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/${environment}/" }
    },
    "RestApiId" : {
        "Value" : { "Ref" : "ApiGatewayApi" }
```

Comment: Thanks @Bruno for your help. though I don't have any resources section for API-Gateway. it is getting created by setting up an event on the lambda function(Function which is in the main serverless.yml template). I only have IAM roles in my resources section. so I am not really sure where to reference the "ApiGateWay" that you suggested above.